# Probing interactions in nlme using the "interactions" package in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme, linearmodels

I am running a linear mixed effects models using the "nlme" package looking at stress and lifestyle as predictors of change in cognition over 4 years in a longitudinal dataset. All variables in the model are continuous variables.
I am able to create the model and get the summary statistics using this code:

```
mod1 <- lme(MS ~ age + sex + edu + GDST1*Time + HLI*Time + GDST1*HLI*Time, random= ~ 1|ID, data=NuAge_long, na.action=na.omit)
summary(mod1)
```

I am trying to use the "interactions" package to probe the 3-way interaction:

```
sim_slopes(model = mod1, pred = Time, modx = GDST1, mod2 = HLI, data = NuAge_long)
```

but am receiving this error:

`Error in if (tcol == "df") tcol <- "t val." : argument is of length zero`

I am also trying to plot the interaction using the same "interactions" package:

```
interact_plot(model = mod1, pred = Time, modx = GDST1, mod2 = HLI, data = NuAge_long)
```

and am receiving this error:

`Error in UseMethod("family") :  no applicable method for 'family' applied to an object of class "lme"`

I can't seem to find what these errors mean and why I'm getting them. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From `?interactions::sim_slopes`:

> The function is tested with ‘lm’, ‘glm’,
> ‘svyglm’, ‘merMod’, ‘rq’, ‘brmsfit’, ‘stanreg’ models. Models
> from other classes may work as well but are not officially
> supported. The model should include the interaction of
> interest.

Note this does **not** include `lme` models.  On the other hand, `merMod` models are those generated by `lme4::[g]lmer()`, and as far as I can tell you should be able to fit this model equally well with `lmer()`:

```r
library(lme4)
mod1 <- lmer(MS ~ age + sex + edu + GDST1*Time + HLI*Time + GDST1*HLI*Time 
               + (1|ID), data=NuAge_long)
```

(things will get harder if you want to specify correlation structures, e.g. `correlation = corAR1()`, which works for `lme()` but not `lmer()` ...)

Comment: Thank you - this worked and I'm able to get the simple slopes and a nice graph from the 3-way interaction.
In addition to the 9 simple slopes of Time on 3MS at each level of the moderators (-1SD, mean, +1SD HLI and -1SD, mean, +1SD GDST1), I want to get the effect of GDST1*Time at each level of HLI. Essentially I wanted to know if GDST1 is associated with change in 3MS (the DV) over time at -1SD, mean, and +1SD HLI --- is there a way to do this with the "interaction" package? Thanks so much again, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't know.  I would imagine that either this package, or the `emmeans` package, would do it ...